# Transport bread maker on Turkish Airlines

Tags: luggage, turkish-airlines, packing

I am flying from London to Tbilisi in a couple of days, on Turkish Airlines with a transfer in Istanbul.  I need to take with me a bread maker - it's well used and doesn't have the original box (lost years ago). I considered packing it into the hand luggage, but due to its size (even though it's not too heavy), it would be rather cumbersome, considering that I'm flying with a small child, so nappies, baby food and the pram take priority.

The other option is to pack it into the checked luggage, but I'm not sure of the best way to do so - to ensure that it doesn't get damaged in transit. It's about 33x27x37 cm, but also has the bread tin inside, which would need to somehow be packed to prevent it banging against the walls inside.

Any ideas about the best way to pack it?

Comment: @pnuts Yep, that's about what I'm thinking. Probably will go with this if nothing better is suggested by tomorrow evening when I start packing.

Comment: @pnuts wrapping in clothes it was. Arrived safe and sound. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of completeness... I packed the bread maker into the checked in luggage, wrapping it in some clothes and wrapping a tea towel around the tin inside it to prevent the tin from moving/banging against the walls inside.  Worked great and got there with no problems.

Answer (score 2):

If it won't fit in your checked luggage you can purchase a cardboard box that will fit reasonably snugly and put some bubble wrap around it. Places like the UPS Store sell such supplies. You may be able to get a free box the right size from a liquor store (grocery store boxes are usually too flimsy). Just pack it up and tape it- I suggest bringing some tape just in case customs wants to have a look see.

Comment: Yes, I've been thinking about this as well.  The main downside of this solution is that it adds an extra item of luggage to what we'll already be dealing with.  I don't think it's a major concern on Turkish though as they only care about the total weight and not the number of items.

Comment: Packed it now - fits very snugly into the suitcase :)

Comment: Great, then you're set. BTW, the Chinese have a slick way of making a carrying handle for cardboard boxes out of packing tape. I'll have to take notes next time I see it done.